# ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) Bluescreen

Tags: windows, drivers, etw

When I want to enable ETW tracing to receive driver events, I do such:

```
logman start "NT Kernel Logger" -p "Windows Kernel Trace" (driver) -o s.etl -ets
```

So on some machine, after running the above command, the computer crashes. After analyzing the memory dump, I figured out that the problem was caused by "TAOKernel64.sys" which is developed by a Chinese company named "Tencent". After removing a program which installed that driver (QQ PC Manager), the problem resolves.

I had two major questions:

**1-**
Does receiving driver events from ETW require all drivers to work properly? So can we have a buggy driver installed and enabled (but not used) and use ETW without causing BSOD? Or I had faced a completely different problem?

**2-**
Can we filter out some of these drivers in ETW (either real-time or offline)? For example, telling ETW not to collect driver events from that .sys file?